# Как правильно вычислить SHA256 хеш набора битов?

Tags: c#, криптография, sha256

Использую класс SHA256 из System.Security.Cryptography для хеширования

Вот код с комментариями: https://pastebin.com/kfpsmLGk

Вот это правильный хеш (справа)
[image: скрин с правильным результатом хеширования на сайте]

А у меня получается вот такое:
[image: скрин с неправильным моим результатом хеширования]

Обобщение про мой код: строка, символизирующая биты, вроде-как абсолютно правильно конвертируется в массив байтов, но sha256 выдает не тот результат, как на сайте. А на сайте он верный, я проверял.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Добавляйте код и конкретную проблему прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Код надо вставлять прямо в пост.

Comment: Почему я не могу сделать это за вас: здесь можно вставлять в пост код только под личную ответственность либо код, написанный лично автором. Представьте, пришел на Stackoverflow рандомный чувак, опубликовал вопрос со ссылкой на код, я иду по ссылке беру код, вставляю в вопрос, а потом выясняется что код защищен лицензией, а я вставив его на Stackoverflow поместил под местную лицензию Creative Commons тем самым нарушив его лицензию, и он идет и подает на меня в суд за то что я украл и расшарил в массы его код, требуя миллион баксов как компенсацию. Поэтому давайте сами.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У Вас проблема с конвертациией массива байт хеша, если использовать этот метод то все будет ок:

```
static string ConvertHashToBinary(byte[] bytes)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        string binary = Convert.ToString(bytes[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
        builder.Append(binary);   
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

PS: Без кода тяжело судить, так что ответ основан на предположениях!)

Comment: Я позже выяснил, что BitArray переворачивает каждый байт, поэтому с ним получилось типа: 00110100 00000001 вместо 00101100 10000000

Comment: Все верно. И BitArray для этой задачи вообще не нужно использовать.

Comment: Если  у Вас получилось решить проблему, можете оформить второй ответ!